# Cant draw a shape to a specific panel in a NetBeans GUI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel

I'm trying to make a simple application to draw shapes to a panel in a `jFrame`. The GUI is a NetBeans generated `jFrame`. The application has three panels. the first two hold button groups to select the shape and a color. There's a button to draw the shape to the third panel once the selections are made.

[What the GUI looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmtX7.jpg)

Unfortunately I'm having no love and can't make it work. For now I just want to get the button to draw a shape then I'll add the button functionality. Here's the code I have so far.

```
private void btnDrawShapeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    Draw shape = new Draw();

    pnlDrawPad.add(shape); //pnlDrawPad is the name of the jPanel

    shape.drawing();

}


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel{

public Draw(){
    super();
}

public void drawing(){
    repaint();
}

//@Override <-- gives error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype" 
public void paintCompnent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawString("Hello World!",40,30);
}
```

}

When I click the "Draw Shape" button nothing happens. I've been searching for a couple days now and am not finding the answer. Actually, its making me more confused as to what to do.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that with NetBeans you don't need to Override the paintComponents() method. Since all the GUI stuff is done when you design it, you merely need to add the drawings to the panel or what ever you need to do. I found you that by declaring and instantiating a 2D graphics object then drawing it to the place you want.

```
private void btnDrawShapeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     

int centerX;    
int centerY; 

Graphics2D drawFx = (Graphics2D)pnlDrawPad.getGraphics();

drawFx.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

centerX = (int)(458*Math.random());
centerY = (int)(440*Math.random());

drawFx.fillOval(centerX-50, centerY-50, 100, 100);

drawFx.dispose();

}
```

Worked like a charm so now every time I push the draw shape button it draws a shape to the panel in a different location every time. I've since put in the radio button functionality to change shape color and fill and added a button to clear the screen.

Not sure if this is the ideal way to do it but for this stupid simple little program it works well enough and I'm done stressing over it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep creating new panels for each shape.

Instead you need a single panel with an ArrayList of objects you want to paint. Then you customize the paintComponent(...) method of the panel to iterate through all the objects in the panel and paint them.

So you button will just add another object to the ArrayList and then invoke repaint() on the panel.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `DrawOnComponent` example shows how to paint a Rectangle objects from an ArrayList to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond but if I'm honest, I have no idea what your taking about. How do you "repaint" radio buttons? or buttons at all? I need the three panels because apparently you cant just put GUI controls on a blank jFrame. So if I have only a single panel what happens to the GUI controls...they just get painted over when I add a shape???

Comment: @CryHavoc_Mike, I have no idea why you find my answer confusing. I gave you a link to complete working code that you can download and test. I guess you didn't take the time to follow the link. If I could take the time to respond the least you can do is take the time to read the link. You can lead a horse to water, but you can't force it to drink.

Comment: I did look at your link. I've been going through the code but just can't rectify how to implement it to do what I need to do. I've tried implementing versions of your statements using the custom code editor for the controls in my GUI but I keep getting errors. In all the stuff I've read about this I keep seeing the statement like yours. "JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw On Component");" But when I try that it throws an error. I've already got a jFrame, why do I need to instantiate another one?

Comment: But when I try to do something like you wrote, "frame.getContentPane().add(drawingArea);" using the name of my jFrame I get massive errors?

Comment: I gave you an example that shows how to do custom painting. There is a `DrawingArea` that shows how to iterate through objects in a List to paint each objdct. There is an `addRectangle(...)` method that shows how to add a new object to the List.  Adding components to a frame is basic Swing. If you don't know how to do this I'm not sure why you are attempting to do custom painting. I have no idea why you are getting errors. I can't teach you basic Java.

Comment: Remember, as I stated in a comment at the start of the code you should not be using a static class. Just create the panel like you would any other panel and add it to the frame.

Comment: Look... I appreciate you trying to help but I would rather take a zero than turn in your code especially if I have to climb a superiority hump. Have you seen the pic of my GUI? The link is in the question I asked above so I have a "basic" understanding of how to add components to a frame. I also know how to loop through an ArrayList of objects. I do it all the time with my database work. Be that as it may, right now my buttons are disabled. I would just like the application to come up with "Hello World" painted across the panel. If I can get it to do that, I can take care of the rest.

Comment: Right now I think my problem is accessing the netbeans generated JFrame. There is this code in the main of my GUI class,  java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ShapesGUI().setVisible(true); Is "ShapesGUI()" the name of the JFrame? I've tried looking through the auto generated code and am not finding a reference to the JFrame.

Comment: `than turn in your code` - I never suggested you turn in my code. I gave you the code to look at to understand the basic concept of what you are asking. It shows 1) how to create a frame 2) add panels to the frame 3) do custom painting on one of those panels. That is the basics of what you are trying to do. You should be able to customize the panels as you wish.

Comment: `I think my problem is accessing the netbeans generated JFrame.` - I always suggest you don't use the IDE to generate your GUI. The code will not be maintainable if you ever move to a different IDE. Now you are spending time learning the IDE and not learning Swing. Use the IDE to help compile and debug your classes. I have never used an IDE so I have no idea on what you need to do.